Why does adding WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false) in MainActivity cause TextView to disappear in Android?
I'm working on an Android application and encountered an issue when adding `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` in the `MainActivity`.
**Problem**: When I add this line in `onCreate` method of `MainActivity`, the content of the `TextView` above and the `fragment` below is not displayed. Only the `fragment` is visible.
Here is the code of my `MainActivity`:
```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat
import com.courses.keyboardanimation.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val binding by lazy {
        ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

    }
}


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TITLE"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="35sp" />


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_conversation"
        android:name="com.courses.keyboardanimation.ConversationFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>



How can I fix this issue so that  the TextView  are visible when using WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)? What i tried:



